# form not processing as JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have the following rails form, and the corresponding controller action has respond_to :js, but rails keeps processing it as HTML. Not really sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

```
form_tag url_for(controller: 'posts', action: 'add_tag'), id: 'enter_tag', remote: true, style: 'display:none' do
  text_field_tag :tag
end
```

UPDATE: removing 'display:none' fixes it (I was having the form fade in.) Why is this?

Comment: I think you need to use form_remote_tag instead of form_tag. Can you try this once?

Comment: `form_remote_tag` is deprecated in newer versions of rails, :remote => true is the option you're supposed to use now.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, are you using Rails 3.1? If so, (I believe, i'm on 3.0.10 still) the jQuery UJS library is automatically includeed.  If that's the case, it should be using a */* datatype request, but I believe rails should notice it's an xhr request and send it to the JS response automatically.

A quick solution may be changing the `url_for` to `url_for(controller: posts, action: 'add_tag', format: 'js')` but I believe it should pick the JS response even without that.  I don't like this approach though because I don't believe it would ever pick your HTML response for non-js Users.

Another fix may be to put `format.js` as your first response format in the controller (it may be HTML now), but I"m missing the reason as to why it's not recognizing it as an Ajax request to begin with?

Comment: ok so taking off the 'display:none' fixed it (I was having the form fade in)

wtf :P